# Logstash Read a Property File

Tags: logstash

I am looking for a way of reading property file in logstash config file so that I can do some data transformation based on the property file value? for example I can skip processing type 1 event and send to index a, process type 2 events and sent to index 2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, note that logstash will read all the files in your config directory.  You can put different processing blocks in different config files, which makes for a nice separation of code.  Be sure that each block is wrapped in a conditional so that they don't all run for all events.